# mysql procedure create table as select (call(abc(xy)))

Tags: mysql, call

I want create table in mysql procedure like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
CREATE TABLE a AS SELECT * FROM (CALL(abcdef(abc)));
```

Any ideas how can I do it or it is impossible in mysql?

Comment: What is the mysql code of the procedure you are calling?

Comment: Procedure abcdef returns 16 rows. Mysql code has about 180 rows.

Comment: Can I insert rows from procedure abcdef into a table? Any ideas or solution how can be this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the syntax in your question, because a stored procedure doesn't return anything (even though it can change the value of some of its parameters, if configured as `OUT` or `INOUT`).

I suggest the following:

- modify the procedure to store the rows in a temporary table:

  ```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table(...);
  INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(...); // do that for all the data
  ```
- After the procedure call, either use directly the table `temp_table` (`SELECT ... FROM temp_table`), or execute the following query:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE a AS SELECT * FROM temp_table;
  ```
- when you no longer need it, you may drop the temporary table. Otherwise, it will be automatically dropped when the MySQL connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I do this? INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (CALL abcdef(abc));

Comment: No, you can't. The reason is the same as with `CREATE TABLE`: a stored procedure doesn't return anything

Comment: Ok, thanks. So now I will try copy the abcdef procedure code into a new procedure.